# $f(x) = \pi + \frac{1}{2}\sin \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right) $ has a unique fixed point on $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: numerical-methods

I am looking for some guidance and help with the following question

> Prove that $$f(x) = \pi + \frac{1}{2}\sin \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right) $$ has a unique fixed point on $[0, 2\pi]$

Comment: use intermediate value theorem

Comment: could you show how this is done?

Comment: thanks for the tips

Comment: @mt12345 You've been here for a while now and asked a few questions, so you should know that it's important to demonstrate effort. This could include showing some attempts you've made to solve the question, or citing results you think might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuous function $h(x) = \pi + \frac{1}{2}\sin \left ( \frac{x}{2}\right) - x $ is positive at 0 and negative at $2\pi$, the interval being $[ \pi, -\pi ]$, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is a point $a \in [0,2\pi]$ with $f(a) - a = 0 $ or $f(a) = a$. This fixed point is unique because h(x) is monotonically decreasing (mentioned by Diger).

---

In general, if the intermediate value theorem for {h(x) = f(x) - x} shows that there is a zero at this function, then there is a point a, such that f(a) - a = 0 or f(a) = a. This fixed point is unique because h(x) is monotonic.

Comment: What about uniqueness?

Comment: Isn't it?
$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \left\{ \pi + \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2} - x \right\} = \frac{\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{4} - 1 < 0 \qquad \forall x \in (0,2\pi)
$$

Comment: thank you for the correction

Comment: I made a mistake because I was looking at the original, f(x) and not the new one

Comment: so now this answer is complete?

Comment: Apparently, we need to add a numerical result, for example, using Mathematica 11.3, `FixedPoint[Function[x, Pi + Sin[x/2]/2], 1.0]`, `Out[]=3.62694`

Comment: @user29418 why did you put a minus x in the equation?

Comment: f(a) - a = 0 or f(a) = a at a. Thats why minus x.

Comment: thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

You may proceed as follow.

- $f([0,2\pi]) \subset [0,2\pi ] \Rightarrow f$ has a fixpoint according to the [fixed point theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FixedPointTheorem.html).
- $|f'(x)| =|\frac{1}{4} \cos \frac{x}{2}| \leq \frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow f$ is contractive, so the fixpoint must be **unique**. To see that assume
  there were $2$ fixpoints $a, b$ with $a \neq b$. Then, you had
  $$|a - b| = |f(a) - f(b)| = |f'(\xi)||a-b| < |a-b| \mbox{ Contradiction! } \Rightarrow a = b$$

Comment: this shows that it has a unique fixed point?

Comment: exactly. it does.